# Ignore lock file when uploading with Office 365 API in python

Tags: python-3.x, sharepoint, office365

I built a module in our pipeline that allows a user, given a specific configuration, to download or upload a file on a specific SharePoint's company folder. My problem is specifically regarding the upload part, I tried to search for someone with the same issues, but could only find something similar.

The issue is: when someone has the file open, the client throws an error if you try to upload a file with the same name in the same folder, saying that it is locked, for example:

```
"name": "ClientRequestException",
    "message": "('-2147018894, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileLockException', \"Die Datei '<site_name>/<site_folder>/<file_name>' ist für die gemeinsame Verwendung durch '<email> [membership]' gesperrt.\", \"423 Client Error: Locked for url: https://<site_name>/_api/Web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(<file-info>)"
```

I found a way to delete the file before uploading, but this reset the version of the file to 1.0 of course. This is the code I am using:

```
from office365.runtime.http.request_options import RequestOptions
from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

def delete(request):
    request.headers['Prefer'] = 'bypass-shared-lock'

credentials = UserCredential(SP_USER, SP_PW)
ctx = ClientContext("<sharepoint-site>").with_credentials(credentials)

# the next three rows are for deleting the existing file
file = ctx.web.get_file_by_server_relative_url("<sharepoint-folder>/<file-name>")
ctx.before_execute(delete)
file.delete_object().execute_query()

# this gets the folder reference
list_folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url("<sharepoint-folder>")

# reads the file and uploads it
with open("<file-name>", 'rb') as lf:
    file_content = lf.read()
        
list_folder.upload_file("<file-name>", file_content).execute_query()
```

note that the `delete` block was just added today as a test, it is not in production (that is why you see a double reference to a folder and to a file within a folder, which sounds redundant)